# avoid to show double popup security alert of my java applet

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet, mixed-code

I created a java applet that uploads a file to a server via ftp, it uses an external library by apache, I signed my applet but when I start the applet from the browser I get two security popups, how do I prevent to show or show only one? hello and thanks

this is the example link:
http://frx08.altervista.org/javaftp/

(the second popup says that the code contains signed and not signed code but I don't know why..)

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Make sure all your code is unsigned, perhaps using `javax.jnlp` available to applets since 6u10. [best route]
- Make sure absolutely all your code is signed (and this includes resource files).
- The "Trusted-Library" feature allows a signed and trusted library to run with untrusted code. It can be very difficult to write the library securely.

Comment: In the java file I use the class org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
and an external sound file, this can cause the problem?

Comment: If they are resource that aren't signed, then yes. If you are loading the sound file via a URL that you don't mean to be a resource but which is under the codebase, then you'll have problems because such connections are indistinguishable from resources. You can switch the codebase off with `<param name="codebase_lookup" value="false">`.